# Temporary DNS server

Tags: bind, dns-hosting, dns-server

What DNS software is good for temporary usage while doing server maintenance?

Since there is not a secondary server available, I would like a solution that can just run on a desktop/laptop just to keep the records updated (preferably without installation -- just reads the existing zone files)

There are backup servers that rely on the master for zone transfers and it would be best not to reconfigure any of the domain record TTLs or the like

Master DNS server is running BIND

Answer (score 2):

BIND, Windows' built-in DNS, PowerDNS, and just about any other DNS server can run just fine on a desktop or laptop or phone or PDA or carrier pigeon. Just copy your BIND zones off the master server and go to town.

Seriously, though. DNS takes minimal resources to run unless you're the kind of place responding to DNS requests in the millions per second.

Comment: Yeah. I dont expect any huge resource drain. Just didn't really want to bother installing and uninstalling all the stuff. Security can be limited as well since it would be run internally just to serve zone-transfer requests (no updates or external queries)

Comment: "apt-get install bind9" should be more than sufficient for installing all the stuff, on a Debian-based host.